# Eclipse PDE: Syntax error, type annotations are available only when source level is at least 1.8

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am having hundreds of the same error: `Syntax error, type annotations are available only when source level is at least 1.8` after installing the [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) Eclipse plug-in. My setup is with Java 7, and I cannot upgrade to Java 8 yet. I have Java 7 and 8 installed, but my JRE and compiler are set to Java 7 via `Window > Preferences > Java`.

I believe that I found the problem, which is related to the `org.eclipse.jdt.annotation` plug-in, described here:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=434033

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

I noticed that I now have two `org.eclipse.jdt.annotation` plug-ins, versions `1.1.0` and `2.0.0`. The problem is that `2.0.0` has a dependency on Java 1.8, and all of my plugins are referencing `2.0.0`. I believe that changing these references to the earlier version should solve this, correct? How can I do this?

As a test, I altered my manifest file on one of my plug-in projects, but it does not remove the errors. Here is an excerpt where I tried to reference the `1.1.0` bundle version:

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.jdt.core,
 org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring,
 org.eclipse.jdt.ui,
 com.kivancmuslu.www.solstice.common,
 com.kivancmuslu.www.util.eclipse,
 com.kivancmuslu.www.util.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor,
 org.eclipse.ui.ide,
 org.eclipse.ui.editors,
 org.eclipse.jface.text,
 com.kivancmuslu.www.utils,
 org.eclipse.ui.console,
 org.eclipse.jdt.annotation;bundle-version="1.1.0"
```

**UPDATE**
Yes, I am running Luna. After changing the last line of my manifest from

```
 org.eclipse.jdt.annotation;bundle-version="1.1.0"
```

to

```
 org.eclipse.jdt.annotation;bundle-version="[1.1.0,2.0.0)"
```

the errors are gone. Thank you.

Comment: The bug report is for Eclipse 4.4 (Luna) - is that what you are running?

Comment: As suggested in the bug report use `[1.1.0,2.0.0)` for the bundle-version on the annotation plugin.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I updated my question above, but is there a way to update the references to `org.eclipse.jdt.annotation` for all of my plug-in manifests in one edit?

Comment: You could probably use `Search > File Search` with the `Replace...` button.

Comment: confirmed, force-using version 1.1.0 of eclipse's annotation jar solves this problem (I also must use Java 7 for this project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big thanks to @greg-449 for bringing up the suggestion mentioned in the bug report, the credit goes to him. I am posting this answer for completeness and to help others:

---

Yes, I am running Luna. After changing the last line of my manifest from

```
 org.eclipse.jdt.annotation;bundle-version="1.1.0"
```

to

```
 org.eclipse.jdt.annotation;bundle-version="[1.1.0,2.0.0)"
```

the errors are gone.